# Boost read_also() function not working with boost::array, cannot use std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, boost

I have this code to open a boost socket, write a command, send the command via the socket, and get the results:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#define MAXSIZE 1000000
//...
void MyClass::processCommand(std::string command)
{
  boost::asio::io_service io;
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io);
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint e(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 60151);  //Info for the connection I need to make...
  this->socket.open(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4());
  this->socket.connect(e);
  this->socket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(command, command.size());
  this->socket.send(boost::asio::buffer(command, command.size());

  boost::array<char, MAXSIZE> buffer;
  this->socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer));
}
```

This code compiles and runs, but freezes on the line calling `read_some()`, and I can't figure out why. If anyone has any ideas for solutions, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You're calling the blocking version of `read_some`, and it's attempting to read up to MAXSIZE bytes.  What is actually being sent by the server? Is the server closing the connection after it's sent?  If you want the non-blocking call, look at `async_read_some` or the `async_read` non-member function

Comment: As far as I know it should not be closing the connection. The code is to communicate with a third-party API, and that API has a specific command to close the connection, so as far as I understand as long as that command is not used it should stay open (though this is my first time working with either Boost or this API so I'm honestly a bit shaky on details, so I may be mistaken)

Comment: @DaveS Also, sorry to have to ask, but I found that the async_read_some function requires a parameter of type "const ReadHandler". I'm having a bit of a hard time finding examples on how to implement this without a bunch of extra functions/classes, and the example on the function's doc page just has "handler" as the parameter. Do you happen to know what a good way to initialize this would be? If so I'd really appreciate it, I think it's probably something easy I'm overlooking but this is my first time ever using Boost and it's a lot to try to learn all at once :/

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `command.size()` bytes.

You then asked to read `MAXSIZE` bytes.

If `command.size()` < `MAXSIZE`, why wouldn't it wait for more bytes to come down the pipe?

Try first writing the size of the packet, then the bytes of the packet.

On the reading side, first read the size of the packet, then read that many bytes of the packet.

`read_some` is free to read less than you requested, but I don't see any documentation that says it must return before it reads as many bytes as you requested.